# How to merge two nested HashMaps in java

Tags: java, hashmap

I have two nested maps and I try to merge two nested maps and produce a output of two merged `HashMap`. Below is the code that I use:

```java
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

HashMap<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("location", "A");
HashMap<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map2.put("geocoordinates", map1);
HashMap<String, Object> map3 = new HashMap<>();
map3.put("TEST", map2);
map.putAll(map3); 

HashMap<String, Object> map11 = new HashMap<>();
map11.put("longitude", "B");
HashMap<String, Object> map12 = new HashMap<>();
map12.put("geocoordinates", map11);
HashMap<String, Object> map13 = new HashMap<>();
map13.put("TEST", map12);

map.putAll(map13); 
System.out.println(map);
```

The output that I get is:

```
   {TEST={geocoordinates={longitude=B}}}
```

But I expected both `longitude` and `location` key to be nested inside `geocoordinates` key but only `longitude` B is there. So, How can I get the combined. How achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

        HashMap<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<>();
        map1.put("location", "A");
        HashMap<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<>();
        map2.put("geocoordinates", map1);
        HashMap<String, Object> map3 = new HashMap<>();
        map3.put("TEST1", map2);
        map.putAll(map3);

        HashMap<String, Object> map11 = new HashMap<>();
        map11.put("longitude", "B");
        HashMap<String, Object> map12 = new HashMap<>();
        map12.put("geocoordinates", map11);
        HashMap<String, Object> map13 = new HashMap<>();
        map13.put("TEST2", map12);

        map.putAll(map13);

        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{TEST2={geocoordinates={longitude=B}}, TEST1={geocoordinates={location=A}}}
```

**Reason**: a `Map` replaces the old value when you put a new value on the same key (in your case, it is `TEST`). Note that `HashMap.putAll()` copies all of the mappings from one map into another. In your code, `map.putAll(map3)` is equivalent of `map.put("TEST",map3)`. And, `map.putAll(map13)` is equivalent of `map.put("TEST",map13)` which replaces the earlier value, `map3` because of the same key, `TEST`.

**Update:** Adding the following update based on the new requirement mentioned in your comment

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        List<HashMap> list=new ArrayList<HashMap>();

        HashMap<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<>();
        map1.put("location", "A");
        list.add(map1);

        HashMap<String, Object> map11 = new HashMap<>();
        map11.put("longitude", "B");
        list.add(map11);

        HashMap<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<>();
        map2.put("geocoordinates", list);       

        map.put("TEST",map2);

        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{TEST={geocoordinates=[{location=A}, {longitude=B}]}}
```

Another way of doing it as follows:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<>();
        map1.put("location", "A");
        map1.put("longitude", "B");

        HashMap<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<>();
        map2.put("geocoordinates", map1);

        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("TEST", map2);

        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{TEST={geocoordinates={location=A, longitude=B}}}
```

Comment: But the input from two string is same. only nested keys longitude and  location should be inside geocoordinates and geocoordinates should be under TEST.How can I get intersection of map.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I wonder if there's a way to achieve the same but with dynamic data. Say a list of dynamic HashMaps that may contain common nested keys up to a certain level

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're seeing is correct – namely, if you have a map and store a new value for an *existing* key, the old value will be lost.

Here's a simple example that isolates what you're doing. In this code, the initial value `"one"` will be overwritten by `"two"`. This is how maps work. In your case, you're using other maps instead of simple strings, but the behavior is the same – you have one value and you're replacing it with another value.

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("TEST", "one");
map.put("TEST", "two");
```

To retain both "one" and "two", you need to either use different keys (ex: "TEST1" and "TEST2"), or alter one of the nested maps stored under "TEST", or introduce an altogether different data structure (such as a [java.util.Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)).